# Git log & Github commit history doesn't sync

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-log

So I'm new to Git and I'm now facing this problem that when I `git log` on *GIT Bash*, it doesn't seem to be synchronized with my github's repo commit history:

[image: git log not synchronized with github repo commit history]

As I remembered, I ever done `git reset --hard <commit-hash>` before but I don't remember to what id. Can you tell me what can I do so it's being syncronized again?

Any helpful answer would be very appreciated!

Comment: have you `git pull`ed? It just looks like your local branch is out of date

Comment: Ohh, so it needs to be pulled first. I thought git log always synced. Thanks!

Comment: Note: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to incorporate commits obtained in the fetch step*. If you're new to Git I advise running the commands separately for learning purposes; later, once you've settled on the two commands and are comfortable with both being run all at once, you can use the `pull` short-cut if you like it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what you've already tried but it looks like you need to do

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

or

```
git pull
```

`git fetch` (implied by `git pull`) fetches the latest state from your origin (ie github).
Normally you don't need to / want to do a `git reset` as that overwrites all local changes. Instead do a `git rebase` to rebase your local changes onto the changes done on origin.

Comment: Yes, I thought before git pull only for receiving files from the remote repository, and git log is always sinced. It's now working, thanks!